# Laravel - Vhost no funciona

Tags: laravel, apache

Tengo Apache 2.4 con Windows y me funciona el virtualhost "a medias". Es decir, tengo esta configuración en el fichero `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/pruebas/api-coches/public"

ServerName api-coches.local
ServerAlias www.api-coches.local
ErrorLog "logs/api-coches.error.log"
CustomLog "logs/api-coches.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Y en el fichero `hosts` de `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc` tengo el siguiente registro

```
127.0.0.1   api-coches.local
```

Luego, en el proyecto de Laravel, tengo definidas estas rutas:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return view('pages.home');
});
Route::get('about', function()
{
    return view('pages.about');
});
Route::get('projects', function()
{
    return view('pages.projects');
});
Route::get('contact', function()
{
    return view('pages.contact');
});
```

Si ejecuto un `php artisan route:list` veo lo siguiente (entre otras rutas):

Pues si pongo en el navegador `http://api-coches.local`, usa la ruta `/` y me devuelve el home.

Pero si intento acceder a `http://api-coches.local/about` me da un 404 de apache, ni siquiera un 404 de laravel.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el `.htaccess`?

Comment: porque no usas laragon que te crea ya automaticamente un host virtual?

Comment: En tu archivo .htaccess es muy posible que el módulo de rewrite no esté habilitado. Puedes activarlo en el PHP ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo tengo configurado de la siguiente manera:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/pruebas/api-coches/public"
    ServerName api-coches.local
    ServerAlias *.api-coches.local
    <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/pruebas/api-coches/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

En el server alias creo que te esta dando problemas el www.
Una vez tuve problemas con el acceso a directorios por eso te recomiendo poner la etiqueta de directory.

Saludos!

Comment: Era eso , 1000 gracias por la ayuda